# initialize map in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to understand this strange behavior

## code

```
private map:Map<string,number>=new Map<string,number>();

callForFlower(cookie:string) : Observable<Map<string,number>>{
    try{
        this.url='https://flower.it/getFlower;
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(this.extractFlower)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }catch(err){
        this.errMsgSubj.next(err)
    }
}
extractFlower(){
    this.addRose();
}
addRose(){
    this.map.set("rose",0)
}
```

when I do map.set I get an exception

> this.map is undefined

why? is there another way to initialize Map object in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `this` in methods passed around like

```
    .map(this.extractFlower)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

you should change it to

```
    .map(this.extractFlower.bind(this))
    .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

or

```
    .map((param) => this.extractFlower(param))
    .catch((param) => this.handleError(param));
```

but this way you have to list all required parameters twice, therefore the first suggestion is usually the preferred one for this use case.